# Splunk query to return events when all the objects of an array where a field value is equal to some value

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need help with splunk query to return events where an array of object contains certain value for a key in all the objects of an array

```
Event 1: { 
            list: [ 
                    {"name": "Hello", "type": "code"}, 
                    {"name": "Hello", "type": "document"}
                   ] 
         } 
Event 2: { 
            list: [ 
                    {"name": "Hello", "type": "code"}, 
                    {"name": "World", "type": "document"}
                   ] 
         } 
Event 3: { 
            list: [ 
                    {"name": "Hello", "type": "document"}, 
                    {"name": "Hello", "type": "document"}
                   ] 
         }
```

filters:
In the list array,

the first item should have "type": "code"

All the items in the list array should have "name": "Hello"

Expected output:
In the above list of events the query should return 'Event 1', where
first item - list[0].type = code and
list has all the items with "name": "Hello"

I tried multiple ways like search

list{}.name="Hello"
This was returning the events which had atleast 1 element having name: Hello

However i was able to achieve checking for 1st filter as below

| eval conflict = mvindex(list, 0)
| spath input=conflict
| search type=code
If someone can help in achieving both the filters in a query that will be helpful.
Thanks in advance